# Set the initial type of a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I'd like to declare an empty vector that accepts insertion of user-defined types. In the following examples `node` is a type I've defined with `classdef node ...`

The following code is rejected by the Matlab interpreter because the empty vector is automatically initialized as type double, so it can't have a `node` inserted into it.

```
>> a = [];
>> a(1) = node(1,1,1);
The following error occurred converting from node to double:
Conversion to double from node is not possible.
```

The code below is accepted because the vector is initialized with a `node` in it, so it can later have nodes inserted.

```
>> a = [node(1,1,1)];
>> a(1) = node(1,2,1);
```

However, I want to create an *empty* vector that can have nodes inserted into it. I can do it awkwardly like this:

```
>> a = [node(1,1,1)];
>> a(1) = [];
```

What's a better way? I'm looking for something that declares the initial type of the empty vector to be `node`. If I could make up the syntax, it would look like:

```
>> a = node[];
```

But that's not valid Matlab syntax. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Empty object can be created by

```
A = MyClass.empty;
```

It works with your **own class**, but also with **Matlab's class** such as

```
A = int16.empty;
```

This method is able to create **multi-dimensional empty** objects with this syntax

```
A = MyClass.empty(n,m,0,p,q);
```

as long as one dimension is set to zero.

*See the [doc](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html).*

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify what your class contains, but yes, generally speaking it is possible to use array creation functions such as `zeros`, `ones`, and others for user-defined classes as well.

For in-built classes, you might have a call like

`A = zeros(2,3,'uint8');`

to create a 2-by-3 matrix of zeros of datatype `uint8`. The similar syntax can also be applied for appropriate types of user-defined classes, for instance:

`A = zeros(2,3,'MyClass');`

where `'MyClass'` is the name of your class, or by giving an example:

```
p = MyClass(...);
A = zeros(2,3,'like',p);
```

The source for this information, along with a specification of how to implement support for array creation funtions in user-defined classes may be found [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-support-for-array-creation-functions.html).

A call such as `zeros(0,0,'MyClass')` would then produce an empty vector of type `MyClass`.