# Is it possible to derive a class from a MATLAB builtin type?

Tags: matlab

I'm experimenting with the idea of creating a read-only matrix type, one that could be passed to existing code and be used like any other matrix, but assignment to a sub-range is prohibited:

```
>> x = ReadOnlyMatrix(...);  % pass in a regular matrix to construct it
>> y = x * 3;  % x can be used like any other matrix
>> x(1,:) = 0; % error! x is read-only
```

I can not find any working examples or documentation for deriving from class 'double'.  Is it possible and can someone provide a small example?

Comment: Have you tried as if deriving from a custom-made class? Or is there any obstacle in the way of that (you might tell I'm not too familiar with matlab classes, but I'm interested).

Comment: You can create a custom class, but override the `subsref` method so that it either throws an error, or doesn't do anything.

Comment: A point of caution: my understanding is that Matlab Object Oriented Programming isn't the most efficient. (But getting better?) People tend not to define classes, etc.. all over the place like you would if you were coding in C++ or Java etc...

Comment: @rayryeng, that was my first approach, but then one has to manually implement every class operator, like +, -, *, /, ^ etc.  I could avoid all of that if I could derive from 'double'.

Comment: @matthew with the new execution engine in r2015b there is no longer a noticeable performance disadvantage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already stated in a comment, I'm not very familiar with matlab classes. However, I tried to tackle your problem none the less. As I've asked in a comment, I'll ask again: why not try to derive a class from double as you would from any other class (and override some methods as @rayryeng suggested)?

Here's what I came up with:

```
classdef myDouble < double
   methods
       function x = myDouble(inval)
           if nargin == 0
               inval = nan;
           end
           x@double(inval);
       end

       function varargout = subsasgn(varargin)
           error('Type myDouble does not support indexing on the lhs!');
       end
   end
end
```

This defines a very simple class `myDouble` derived from the class `double`. It has a constructor which initializes the object to any double array (or `NaN` for an empty call), and overrides the [`subsasgn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html) method of `double`s which is responsible for assignments of the kind `A(I)=B`.

Since I didn't override the `disp` method (for now, to keep matters clear), the default appearance is a bit verbose. Default initialization:

```
>> myvar = myDouble()

myvar = 

  myDouble

  double data:
   NaN

  Methods, Superclasses
```

Initializing with an array:

```
>> myvar = myDouble(magic(3))

myvar = 

  myDouble

  double data:
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

  Methods, Superclasses
```

Using the array as a matrix:

```
>> myvar.^2

ans =

    64     1    36
     9    25    49
    16    81     4

>> diag(myvar)

ans =

     8
     5
     2
```

You can see that all the operations and methods which are defined in the `double` superclass seem to work, but return objects of class `double` (which is both understandable and useful).

We can also access subarrays:

```
>> myvar(2,:)

ans = 

  myDouble

  double data:
     3     5     7

  Methods, Superclasses
```

which will return an object of the same type.

So let's try overwriting some elements:

```
>> myvar(2,2) = 3
Error using myDouble/subsasgn (line 11)
Type myDouble does not support indexing on the lhs!

>> myvar(2,:) = [3; 2]
Error using myDouble/subsasgn (line 11)
Type myDouble does not support indexing on the lhs!

>> myvar  %make sure it's intact '

myvar = 

  myDouble

  double data:
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

  Methods, Superclasses
```

The overridden `subsasgn` method does what it should: it throws an error, regardless of whether the input would be a valid assignment with `double` arrays (in the latter example: it wouldn't).

I also threw in a rudimentary `disp` method to make our class more sneaky:

```
       function disp(obj)
           disp(double(obj));
       end
```

The resulting output compared to an actual `double`:

```
>> magic(3)

ans =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> myDouble(magic(3))

ans = 

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Comment: This looks like what I want.  I was trying to derive from double but had declared my matrix as a property, and getting an obscure error.  Unfortunately, (or fortunatly) I won't be back in the office until after the holidays to try your approach.  If it works, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Good work! To make `myDouble` even more consistent with the original `double` class, how about trying to take advantage of the `empty` method as described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34333817/5471520) instead of assigning a 1x1 `NaN` array?

Comment: @mikkola thank you, after my initial arbitrary `NaN` initialization I did try essentially an `empty` with `inval=[]`. Actually, that would probably be equivalent to not checking `nargin` at all, and just throwing the initializing `inval` into `double()`. The problem is that my simple `disp` hack doesn't display anything for an empty array, unlike an empty `double`. A more elegant `empty`-based attempt seems to give the same. I tried playing around with `display`, but no success. Any ideas?